# dropdown is working in desktop but not in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, attributes, dropdown

Dropdown element is working fine on desktop view but not on mobile view. Click and hover events are not working. What should I do, so them will work on mobile view. I am a new learner stuck with this problem,  I tried to google it but couldn't find any solution.

```
<div class='dropdown-table'>
   <button class='dropbtn dottedOpenOrders'>&#xFE19;</button>
   <div class='dropdown-content'>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="tooltip" class="btn btn-xs btn-default btn-edit-order" data-order_location=${openOrder.location} data-order_id=${openOrder.id} data-order_type='${openOrder.type}' data-order_action=${openOrder.action} data-group_id=${openOrder.public_id}><span><img src="img/edit-dropdown.png" /> </span><span>Edit</span></a>                                         
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="tooltip" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btn-close-order" data-order_location=${openOrder.location} data-order_id=${openOrder.id} data-order_type='${openOrder.type}' data-order_action=${openOrder.action} data-group_id=${openOrder.public_id}><span><img src="img/cancel-dropdown.png" /> </span> <span>Cancel </span> </a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="tooltip" class="btn btn-xs btn-default btn-play-pause-order" data-order_location=${openOrder.location} data-order_id=${openOrder.id} data-order_type='${openOrder.type}' data-order_action=${openOrder.action} data-group_id=${openOrder.public_id}><span><img src="img/pause-dropdown.png" /> </span> <span>Pause/Resume </span> </a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="tooltip" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning btn-exit-order" data-order_location=${openOrder.location} data-order_id=${openOrder.id} data-order_type='${openOrder.type}' data-order_action=${openOrder.action} data-group_id=${openOrder.public_id}><span><img src="img/exit-dropdown.png" /> </span> <span>Force exit </span> </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: there is no hover event on mobile

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.